# Is yoasts seo plugin only for sites hosted by wordpress

Tags: html

I'm hoping I chose the correct stackexchange site to post this. Also excuse my stupidity if the answer is obvious. I'm looking to use yoasts wordpress seo plugin but built my site myself and hosted it with onlydomains.

Is there a way I can use this seo plugin through a third party hosting site or will I have to switch my hosting to wordpress and go from there?

Or are there other alternatives to yoasts plugin which I can use.

Comment: Migrated it to here so they might answer the "alternative" part. Your question is really two questions though and the first part might be on-topic for Superuser if they know a way to use Yoast.

Comment: cheers ryan, you're the man.

Answer (score 1):

I doubt this is the right stack but not sure if stackoverflow is right either. I'm sure anyone else can tell you. In the mean time:

I think a quick look at his websites instantly gives you all the answers you need... ;)

[image]

So as you can tell, they have a wordpress plugin and a drupal module. Since it's written for wordpress you won't be able to use it for anything else.

Comment: How did I miss that, looks like you might be right. I'll wait a day or two before marking this correct in case there is a way.